# Data Source Name Not Found and No Default Driver Specified when creating Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a VBA macro in Microsoft Excel for Office 365 -64 bit, where I get the error.

> Data Source Name Not Found and No Default Driver Specified

on the `.CreatePivottable` line

Part of the macro is given below.

```vb
' add a sheet and put it at the end
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Pivotsheet

On Error GoTo 0
        
' create the pivot cache
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlExternal)
    .Connection = "ODBC;DBQ=;DefaultDir=;Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};"
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & csvname
    .CreatePivotTable Range("A3"), PivotName
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Finish:
End Sub
```

This macro runs in MS Office 2010 32 bit and in MS office 2016 - 32 bit.
I checked this on Google, could not find something concrete.

I have the following files in system.
C:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: I'm presuming that you are getting the error on `.Connection =...` line? not sure what you mean by: **I am getting the error in subject line?**

Comment: `DBQ=;DefaultDir=` Your parameters are empty? It should be something like `DBQ=C:\SampleDir\Sample.xls;DefaultDir=C:\SampleDir...`

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error in .CreatePivottable line and error is Run time 1004: Data Source Name Not Found and No Default Driver Specified. Also regarding the parameters it was empty earlier too, which was working fine and this code has other part as well where it call the file required and we select it from the required drive.